# min max values of a List<double[]>

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I have an array

```
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
values.add(new double[] { 12.3, 12.5, 13.8, 16.8, 20.4, 24.4, 26.4, 26.1, 23.6, 20.3, 17.2,
    13.9 });
values.add(new double[] { 10, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 26, 26, 23, 18, 14, 11 });
values.add(new double[] { 5, 5.3, 8, 12, 17, 22, 24.2, 24, 19, 15, 9, 6 });
values.add(new double[] { 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 26, 25, 22, 18, 13, 10 });
```

How can i find the max and min values?

Comment: collection.min but it complain about the double[]

Comment: what are you searching actually? A List<MinMax> with the max/min values for each list entry? One single min and one single max value of type double[]? If so, how to compare two double[]?

Comment: i basically want the min and max value of those values in the exmaple. Or if that cant be done then the max and min value of each line .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
double min=Double.MAX_VALUE, max=Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (double[] ds : values) {
    for (double d : ds) {
        if (d > max) max=d;
        if (d < min ) min=d;

    }
}
```

Comment: that seems to have done the trick thanks. Is there any reason why i cant use the collections min rotuine?

Comment: double are primitives, Collections.min() requires non-primitives and you can't autoboxing arrays.

Answer (score 1):

this method will be useful too:

```
public double getMaxValue(List<Double> values){
   double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;
   for(Double d : values){
      if(d > maxValue){
         d = maxValue
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this one, its has more cohesion.